# gnu parallel pipe sed remove backtick symbol

Tags: linux, sed, gnu-parallel

eg. I have a test.sql

```
cat test.sql
INSERT INTO `t_zydx` VALUES 77.2148,
```

and i wanna replace ` to empty

by using `sed` it works fine

```
sed s/\`//g test.sql
INSERT INTO t_zydx VALUES 77.2148,
```

but when i using parallel pipe

```
cat test.sql | parallel --pipe sed s/\`//g
```

it shows

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Besides a syntax error, I don't see the problem you want to solve

Comment: I'm trying remove the `backtick` symbol by using `parallel --pipe sed`, but it is not working

Comment: Why do you want to use parallel for that?

Comment: for example, if i have a sql file like 20GB, does parallel will faster than just using sed?

Comment: you would need to split it, process it, and then rejoin it. I doubt that this brings any benefit with a 20G file.

Comment: @hek2mgl See edited answer.

Comment: @OleTange Interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the command:

```
cat test.sql | parallel -q --pipe sed s/\`//g
```

or:

```
cat test.sql | parallel --pipe sed 's/\`//g'
```

> for example, if i have a sql file like 20GB, does parallel process faster than just using `sed`?

Probably not. `--pipe` is slow. It maxes out at around 500 MB/s. But `--pipepart` maxes out at around 1 GB/s *per core*. So on a 4-core with hyperthreading (8 "cores") I can get 5 GB/s.

This will divide the size of `test.sql` by the number of cores, and pass full line chunks of that size to `sed`:

```
parallel --pipepart --block -1 -a test.sql sed 's/\`//g'
```

GNU Parallel will buffer output on disk, so this may now be the limiting factor. This is more or less what happens:

```
read test.sql
save processed output to /tmp
read processed output from /tmp
print to stdout
```

If you do not care about the order - you just want full lines, then you can avoid the middle two `save` and `read` by using `--line-buffer` (from version 20170822):

```
# Chop input into one chunk per core
# process chunk
parallel --pipepart --block -1 -a test.sql --line-buffer sed 's/\`//g'
```

This way you avoid temporary storage of the 20 GB, but only read 20 GB from disk once and write 20 GB on standard output.